# All code works instantly, but I need to gradually

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement, boolean

I have an object that should be turned on with the ESCAPE key and turned off also with the ESCAPE key. I wrote the code, but for some reason when I press ESCAPE everything works at once, as soon as the `boolean` changes, the second code also works.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MouseCursor : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject pause;
bool bool_determine = false;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)){
        if(bool_determine){
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = true;
            pause.SetActive(true);
            bool_determine = true;
            Debug.Log("hey1" + bool_determine);
        }else{
        if(!bool_determine){
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.visible = false;
            pause.SetActive(false);
            bool_determine = false;
            Debug.Log("hey2" + bool_determine);
        }
        }
        }
            
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a tip: there's no point to check that `if (!bool_determine)` inside of the `else` block for `if(bool_determine)`. The **only** way the code could even get to that if statement is if `bool_determine` is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure. But I kind of found some issues.
You are setting bool_determine false when it is already false, and true when it is already true.

And I guess you could optimize the code a little bit:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)){
    bool_determine = !bool_determine;
    Cursor.visible = bool_determine;
    pause.SetActive(bool_determine);
    Debug.Log("Helo " + bool_determine);
}
```

Great if I could help

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't even think that I could put a bool in `setActive`

Comment: Appreciate it :)

Comment: @Poka `I didn't even think that I could put a bool in setActive` .. what do you think of what type `true` and `false` are? ;)